# Why haven’t I got this badge yet?

Tags: support, badges

I have gotten 30 of the required 30 days with well received questions required to get inquisitive and yet I’ve not been awarded the badge, why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to maintain a [positive question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/380389). This means that you need

$$ \frac{\text{closed}+\text{negative score}+\text{deleted}}{\text{total questions}} < 0.5 $$

Note that closed, negative score and deleted questions count triple against you.

If my count is correct, you have 21 questions with a negative score, 26 deleted questions, and 36 closed questions. Since you have 138 total questions, you will need 28 more questions if all of your questions are well-received to get to a positive question record.

Answer (score 2):

The full text of the [Inquisitive badge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/195/inquisitive) is,

> Ask a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintain a positive question record.

While you have asked questions on 30 separate days (hence the 30/30), you have [several questions with downvotes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A263465+is%3Aq+score%3A-100..-1) and some that are closed (not sure if this means anything with regards to the inquisitive badge, however).

So you haven't gotten the badge because you haven't yet met the qualifications for it.

Comment: How do I determien how closwe I am to a "postitive question record?"

Comment: You probably can't would be my first guess, but I don't otherwise know. I believe it to be one of those secret things the StackExchange team doesn't want people to know because they could game the system (as opposed to simply asking/answering questions).

Comment: Well given Chris's answer, I stand corrected; there is indeed a public equation for positive question count.